# The unification algorithm in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to program the unification algorithm in Prolog to verify if two expressions can unify by returning boolean True/False:

EDIT.
I found this implementation usefull:
from: [http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/data_struct.html](http://kti.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ebartak/prolog/data_struct.html)

````
unify(A,B):-
   atomic(A),atomic(B),A=B.
unify(A,B):-
   var(A),A=B.            % without occurs check
unify(A,B):-
   nonvar(A),var(B),A=B.  % without occurs check
unify(A,B):-
   compound(A),compound(B),
   A=..[F|ArgsA],B=..[F|ArgsB],
   unify_args(ArgsA,ArgsB).
   
unify_args([A|TA],[B|TB]):-
   unify(A,B),
   unify_args(TA,TB).
unify_args([],[]).```
````

Comment: `(=)/2` is the implentation of the unification algorithm. So you can unify `mayor(padre(Y),Y) = mayor(padre(Z), juan)`.

Comment: Not clear what is being asked here. Do you need to just unify things (use `=/2` as @WillemVanOnsem suggested), or do you need to implement a custom unification algorithm that is different from Prolog's unification?

Comment: I need to implement a custom unification algorithm, with Prolog

Comment: But how is it different than the built-in unification?

Comment: @TA_intern It is probably not supposed to be different from the built in unification but just a finger exercice to better understand how unification works. The best way to understand how something works is often to try and implement it for yourself.

Comment: @KimMens If you read the comments under the only answer to this question, you will see why I am struggling to understand the purpose of this, even as a finger exercise. On the other hand, I am just a teaching assistant intern so I still have a lot to learn myself.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial implementation of something like the Martelli and Montanari unification algorithm described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#A_unification_algorithm. The comments for each part refer to the corresponding rewrite rule from the algorithm. Note that there is no need for an explicit conflict rule, we can just fail if no other rule applies.

```
% assuming a universe with function symbols g/2, p/2, q/2

% identical terms unify (delete rule)
unify(X, Y) :-
    X == Y,
    !.

% a variable unifies with anything (eliminate rule)
unify(X, Y) :-
    var(X),
    !,
    X = Y.

% an equation Term = Variable can be solved as Variable = Term (swap rule)
unify(X, Y) :-
    var(Y),
    !,
    unify(Y, X).

% given equal function symbols, unify the arguments (decompose rule)
unify(g(A, B), g(X, Y)) :-
    unify(A, X),
    unify(B, Y).
unify(p(A, B), p(X, Y)) :-
    unify(A, X),
    unify(B, Y).
unify(q(A, B), q(X, Y)) :-
    unify(A, X),
    unify(B, Y).
```

Examples:

```
?- unify(q(Y,g(a,b)), p(g(X,X),Y)).
false.

?- unify(q(Y,g(a,b)), q(g(X,X),Y)).
false.

?- unify(q(Y,g(a,a)), q(g(X,X),Y)).
Y = g(a, a),
X = a.
```

One or two things remain for you to do:

- Generalize the decompose rule to deal with arbitrary terms. You might find the `=..` operator useful. For example:

  ```
    ?- Term = r(a, b, c), Term =.. FunctorAndArgs, [Functor | Args] = FunctorAndArgs.
    Term = r(a, b, c),
    FunctorAndArgs = [r, a, b, c],
    Functor = r,
    Args = [a, b, c].
  ```

  You will need to check if two terms have the same functor and the same number of arguments, and whether all corresponding pairs of arguments unify.
- Find out if your professor would like you to implement the occurs check, and if yes, implement it.

Comment: It doesn't seem that the unification you are using is at all necessary. It seems that equivalence is enough, OP writes in their question: "the follow examples can be unified by returning a boolean True/False". Still not sure what should happen to free variables that are not yet unified... maybe this is supposed to be a reimplementation of "unifiable".

Comment: Or maybe you can wrap the unification in double negation so that it is undone? Compare `?- X = Y, X ==Y.` to `?- \+ \+ X = Y, X == Y.`

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. It's a common homework assignment to reimplement something that already exists. I actually think that implementing unification in this way is a reasonable aid for understanding.

Comment: Hmm. You are bottoming out at the built-in unification though. Talk about the snake biting its own tail..... Either the assignment is complete waste of everyone's time (your and mine, too), or there is something about the assignment that OP is not sharing with us. Why implement this in Prolog (and not C or Python or Java or whatever) if it is the exact same unification that you'll end up using in the implementation of the "custom" unification?

Comment: At the very least, I would expect it to not further instantiate its arguments (if it "returns" a true/false, so probably succeeds/fails without further instantiating the two sides of the "custom unification")? Or have I really lost touch with how pointless education really is?

Comment: Bottoming out at variables is fair, since it's just modification of a pointer. There is no snake biting its own tail behind the scenes. The Prolog system will *not* duplicate any of the recursive work, it will just bind that pointer. If there were a builtin `bind_variable_to_term_without_checking_anything/2` predicate, I would have used that instead of `=/2`. But the variable case of `=/2` is exactly that.

Comment: *a variable unifies with anything* that is not Martelli Montanari.

Comment: Do you mean the occurs check? I mentioned it explicitly as a possible TODO. And I wrote that my implementation was "something like" Martelli and Montanari.