# How can I improve error reporting using PlUnit?

Tags: prolog, diff, swi-prolog, edit-distance, plunit

I'm writing tests using SWI-Prolog's [PlUnit](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) and would like to provide a better error message, perhaps by diffing what I've got from what I was expecting.

The following minimal working example (MWE) exemplifies what I'm after:

```
:- module(mwe, [parse_int/2]).

parse_int(Str, Num) :- number_string(Num, Str):

:- begin_tests(mwe).
:- use_module(mwe).

testcase("1", 1).
testcase("10", 10).
testcase("100000000000", 10000000000). % Oops
test("parse int", [forall(testcase(Text, Want))]) :-
  parse_int(Text, Got),
  assertion(Got = Want).

:- end_tests(mwe).
```

The output is:

```
% PL-Unit: mwe ..
ERROR: /home/bkim/Projects/swifun/mwe.pl:11:
    test parse int (forall bindings = ["100000000000",10000000000]): assertion failed
    Assertion: 100000000000=10000000000
false.
```

A differ, similar to [go-cmp](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp#Diff), could present this result like:

```
- 100000000000
+ 10000000000
```

Which is easier to compare at a glance.

I couldn't find anything that performs this type of check for general Prolog terms, the closer being an example of [edit distance between lists](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/memoization).

Comment: `assertion(Got = Want).` is using unification. You want comparison with `==`. After seeing that I didn't look for more problems.

Comment: I would write a full answer but in checking to see if you either accept previous answers to your [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/946814/bruno-kim?tab=questions) or give feedback as to why you are not accepting answers I see that you are not always doing this.

Comment: Guy Coder, the question is about using a better lib for comparing terms instead of = or ==. I do want unification because I can use anonymous vars in `Want` to ignore pieces of `Got` thatdon't interest me. Thanks for the heads-up regarding accepting answers, I went back and accepted some that I had ignored.

Comment: Most of what you seek should be derivable from this, [Adding some color to your text messages](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/adding-some-color-to-your-text-messages/2002). If so then post your own answer and get some points. If not then I can post a full answer. Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the comparison into the test rule's head:

```
test("parse int", [forall(testcase(Text, Want)), Got = Want]) :-
    parse_int(Text, Got).
```

This way it's more explicit what you want the test to express. And it allows PlUnit to give more informative output:

```
ERROR: /home/isabelle/foo.pl:11:
    test parse int (forall bindings = ["100000000000",10000000000]): wrong answer (compared using =)
ERROR:     Expected: 10000000000
ERROR:     Got:      100000000000
```

Comment: That's a better error message! I changed the question's title to focus more on messaging and less on diffing. If you're reading this in the future, I'd still like to know about a diffing library, tho :)

Comment: Maybe a few more examples would help. For this particular example you might as well just define `eq(X, Y) :- ( X = Y ->  true ; format('expected: ~w~ngot:      ~w~n', [X, Y]) ).` I imagine that you want something more sophisticated,

Comment: Yes, in Go I rely heavily on go-cmp to compare complex data structures. My project in Prolog is a programming language parser, so I'd like to diff parse trees and spot just what changes if a test fails

Comment: You could start with an implementation of unification like the one at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64666286/4391743 and report a mismatch at the first place where it fails (i.e., no rule applies). Then maybe extend that to a sort of minimum edit distance computation on trees if you wish.